# How to configure JSF and Apache to use a domain name on port 80?

Tags: apache

I am currently trying to setup my server on port 80 and I cannot seem to get it to work correctly. I am currently using Intellij as an IDE and have no idea why this is not working. I first tried just going to Run/Debug configurations and changing the tomcat server settings there to port 80. This worked and would run the application. Only issue is that it would just go to a blank screen when localhost was typed into the url. If I put any other port 8080 808 anything from what I can tell it works perfect. But port 80 is goes straight to a blank page. Also I have a question on if I should open the port up. I know to connect externally you need to open a port up on your router, but if I am not mistaken port 80 is used for a lot of web stuff. So should I still open the port up on my router for this computer? (That is the least of my issues as of right now tho) I just want to make sure I am doing it right. I currently have it opened. Here is how I have things set up.

I put my Apache file in my project so I have src -> main -> bin, confi, java, lib, logs, temp, webapp, webapps, work, and some other files. I have no made any server config changes on the actual server.xml in apache, I am not sure if I have to if I am using intellij. If anyone can let me know what I am doing wrong that would be awesome. I am currently using tomcat 8.0.14. Thanks a lot! If you need any additional information please let me know!

[image]

[image]

Namecheap screenshot VVVVVVV

[image]

Comment: So one of the issues was that Skype was using port 80 on my computer. So now I can get to localhost without any issues but..... I cannot connect through my DSN name. www.mywebsite.com does the same thing as localhost was doing. So for whatever reason it cannot find it.

Comment: Can you add screen shots of your DNS settings? DNS is usually simple enough to fix.

Comment: Do you mean the server.xml? Or is this screenshot of namecheap what you wanted? Also the ip address/url is just my ip like 222.22.22.22. And as far as the server.xml I did not really change anything, maybe that is the issue? Is there something that I have to change other than the IDE? I tried a few things like adding a <host> with the name of the domain hosting. If thats what you want me to upload I can do that too.

Comment: I am a bit confused. I assume that you registered a domain name through namecheap. If that is the case, you should have an A record for that domain name that points to your host or server IP address. This would be done with namecheap. Your www can be an A record or better, a CNAME that points to your domain name- www.example.com -> example.com. This is traditional. Your server host name should be your domain name and your web server should have the domain name in the configuration. I am not familiar with server.xml configurations. But I do know Apache.

Comment: The screenshot is from namecheap, showing that Record type A (Address) to my ip address. I uploaded the image already. Also I was meaning the server.xml in Apache when I said Server.xml. Something is just not connecting correctly and I am thinking it could be because of the settings or something of the sort. I am not exactly sure how this domain names work very well.

Comment: It is simple. When you register a domain name, you then assign, typically in your registrars DNS, an A record that is your domain name - A - and your public IP address. Then you create a CNAME that point www.example.com to example.com. An MX record is needed for e-mail. Generally, that is it. But on your end, your public IP address must exist in a firewall/router or on your server. Your client computer must be able to ping your public IP address and nslookup (your domain name) should resolve to your IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the first issue had to do with skype. The second issue that I was having was some issues in the Apache server.xml. I reverted the xml file to its original state and everything started working without any issues. If port 80 is not working for you just make sure that you change skype so that it no longer uses port 80. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Congratulations!! I am glad it worked out. We are here anytime if you need us.